# My whirlpool duet dryer quit heating. Found a melted wire

Tags: repair

I have a Whirlpool duet dryer, model number WED8300SW1. It quit heating, today I found a wire that has been melted. It looks like a thermal fuse BUT, I have several of these fuses and they all look like a thermal fuse. I have looked at several pictures of the inside of my machine and can not find where I had the burnt wire. Since the wire is burnt do I need to replace the fuse or can I just reconnect the wire?

[image]

In this picture it is the one on the right as you can see the connecter is still on the top part this is the one that melted

Comment: I would not call that a fuse

Comment: The round thing with two wire connections could be a thermal fuse; the wire itself isn't. I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at in the picture - the red wire? are you sure it is burned and not just dirty?

Comment: @user253751 he is referring to the ceramic thing way on the top right

Comment: There should be a wiring diagram inside the dryer, probably in the control panel.  If not, find one online.  If you can't read and trace through the wiring diagram, you really should call a professional to fix this for you.

Comment: @KyleB, I have provided a complete explanation with wiring diagram.   I don't believe this individual is particpating in his own post aside from rather unusual downvoting on my thorough answer.   I repair washers and dryers  for living.

Comment: @Meta_Alchemy That was extremely kind of you to post all that.   You hadn't posted a schematic prior to my comment else I'd obviously not said anything!    OP should say thank you, and/or select your answer.   I suspect OP was just looking for "Tie red wire here" and your post is too much to absorb, hence the downvote?  (wasn't me BTW FWIW)    So I'm back to my 1st thought "Call a professional"  ;)

Comment: I have sent another picture.  Bigger

Comment: I am a female so bare with me

Comment: @KyleB, Apparently, I was right.  I refused to accept the story that was told in the post about the burnt wire connector on that heating element.  I didn't get all these wrinkles for nothing.  And so here it is:  " I BELIEVE B GETS CONNECTED TO E, AND A TO F". I just happened to see OP telling Ruskie letting him know that he was right about the wire A and B instead of replying to me.  Look below and see what I mean. :-)

Comment: @KennethaHigdon, What "another picture" did you post?  Plus more, you might consider looking closely WHO  provided you a thorough answer as to what wires should connect to pins of the heating element  and with all the diagrams to show it and having ruled out the whole story about that burnt wire connector?  Who did you reply to about being right about it?

Comment: You did Sir and I thank you from the Bottom of my heart. Happy Thanksgiving

Answer (score 2):

[image: limit switches and heating element]

I am including the picture you have in your post and talk about it.

Okay, take a look at wire A, B, C, and D

Wire A and B is not connected to anything.

Please provide larger picture so I can see where each wire B and C and D goes to at their other ends.

I want to see if wire C goes to upper thermolimit switch along with wire D.
Then I want to see the other end of wire B also.

Then I will explain exactly what you should do.
**I BELIEVE B GETS CONNECTED TO E, AND A TO F**.

(While you are at it, check for resistance on the two pins of heating element ( E and F) to see if you are reading around 10 ohms. and check resistance on the pins of that thermoswitch as well, you should read full continuity and also the one on the top side, the top one, the limit cut off switch)

Look closely at the color of wires in the diagram.

I can't see a corresponding wire that is burned aside from the fact that you are not participating in your own post.

who is doing the constant unnecessary downvoting.   Please find something better to do.  Not good. I know everything there is to know about dryers. You should extend yourself and others some respect.

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: You're right, we need a bigger picture and yes, we do have mystery DVers.  I originally thought B went to E but zooming in on E, there's a burnt connector still there so I was thinking C went to E.  but without a better picture, we won't know. +1

Comment: On certain revisions of iOS, the "hitbox" for the downvote button is *enormous* so easy to press by accident.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, donwvote is easy to press, in fact 2 of them in a row. At the same time upvote was easy to press, in fact again 2 of them on the post itself, a post that I refused that it was clear in its content.   I ended up making my own assumption and now, look below, OP admitting not to me but to the wrong person that he was right about the two wires instead of telling me.  Look below you will see it.   Incidently somehow the 2 downvotes turned into 2 upvotes instead, just like magic.  :-)